# How can I echo certain content for each custom taxonomy?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have a page where I want to display repair prices for various smartphones.
I created the custom post type "Reparaturpreise" (repair prices) and also the custom taxonomy "Marken" (brands).
For every brand I would like to display the brand name as a heading and below there should be a table which lists various repair prices.

This is the code I have so far:

```
<?php
               $args = array(
                           'taxonomy' => 'marke',
                           'orderby' => 'name',
                           'order'   => 'ASC'
                       );

               $cats = get_categories($args);

               foreach($cats as $cat) {
            ?>
            
            <h2><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'marke', '', ', ' ));?></h2>
                  
            <?php 
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'reparaturpreise',
                        'category'  => 'apple',
                        'posts_per_page' => 999
                    );
                    
                    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
                ?>
                
                    <table class="repair-prices-list">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Gerät</th>
                            <th>Display</th>
                            <th>Akku</th>
                            <th>Backcover</th>
                        </tr>

                        <?php
                            if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
                            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
                        ?>

                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'marke', '', ', ' ));?> <?php the_title(); ?></td>
                            <td>€ <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'displayreparatur', true); ?>,-</td>
                            <td>€ <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'akkutausch', true); ?>,-</td>
                            <td>€ <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'backcover-reparatur', true); ?>,-</td>
                        </tr>


                                <?php
                                    wp_reset_postdata();
                                    endwhile;
                                    endif;
                                ?>

                    </table>
            <?php
               }
            ?>
```

Right now it shows 3 tables, but all with the same heading (first brand) and every table shows all of the phones, not filtered by brand.

You can see the current output here:
https://relaunch.websolute.at/reparaturpreise/

Thank you in advance for your help and sorry if my english is not the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work it out myself, this is the code I used:

```
<?php
            
            $custom_terms = get_terms('marke');

            foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
                wp_reset_query();
                $args = array('post_type' => 'reparaturpreise',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'marke',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
                        ),
                    ),
                 );

                 $loop = new WP_Query($args);
                 if($loop->have_posts()) {
                    echo '<h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2>'; ?>

                    <table class="repair-prices-list">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Gerät</th>
                            <th>Display</th>
                            <th>Akku</th>
                            <th>Backcover</th>
                        </tr>
                                    
                    <?php
                    
                    while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'marke', '', ', ' ));?> <?php the_title(); ?></td>
                            <td>€ <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'displayreparatur', true); ?>,-</td>
                            <td>€ <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'akkutausch', true); ?>,-</td>
                            <td>€ <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'backcover-reparatur', true); ?>,-</td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    endwhile;
                     
                    ?>
                    
                    </table>
            
            <?php
                        
                 }
            }
            
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have:
`<h2><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'marke', '', ', ' ));?></h2>`

Try:
`<h2><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, $cat, '', ', ' ));?></h2>`

As you are trying to get the different cats.

Also you can change `posts_per_page` to `-1` for the same 'unlimited' results.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I change 'marke' to $cat, the page goes blank.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned it was untested. Was just a thought.